# WebView load in simulator but not in device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview

My app load the website in the simulator but when I ran on the device It didn't appear

Is it a xcode problem? or maybe an update problem (My iPhone show me that is ready to update but I didn't)

This is my code

```
#import "twitterViewController.h"

@interface twitterViewController ()

@end

@implementation twitterViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSString *webSite=@"https://www.youtube.com/"; //It's like a template page
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:webSite];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    [twitterWeb loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: Can you go to the web page you are trying to load in Safari on the device?  Does it load there? Are you getting any error messages in the Device Console when you are running on the device?

Comment: what is your real URl ?

Answer (score 0):

Load the website in the simulator but when I ran on the device It didn't appear then,

May be something wrong case in filenames. means ,suppose your file wanted to load file 'Abc.js' whereas its name was 'abc.js.

you should check your 'url'